# EXCEL: Return a row value based on the row with highest max value

Tags: excel

I've seen some similar questions for this, however none were suited correctly.

I'm wondering if I can return a row cell based on the max value in the same row, but different cell.

So I have this;

```
 | A | B | Date 
1| X | 2 | 01/01/17
2| Y | 3 | 17/01/17
3| Z | 4 | 18/01/17
4| X | 2 | 21/01/17
5| Y | 3 | 03/02/17
6| Z | 4 | 03/02/17
7| Z | 4 | 07/03/17
8| Z | 4 | 09/03/17
9| Y | 3 | 13/03/17
```

So Column A displays a string, and Column B counts how many times that Column A string is repeated. I have another sheet with a row for each month, being 01, 02, 03, 04, etc. I am trying to get the string from Column A, which the highest value in Column B, grouped by each month. So for the above example, the next sheet would look as so;

```
 |   A  | B 
1| X    | 2
2| Draw | 1
3| Z    | 2
```

I have been able to achieve the date grouping aspect for similar functions using;

```
IFS(E:E,D:D,">=" & DATE(A$2,B6,1),D:D,"<=" & DATE(A$2,B6,EOMONTH(B6,0)))
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I could achieve this, it would be much appreciated!

---

Edit;
I've managed to figure parts of it out, I have been able to get the most common name (without checking for multiples) using

```
=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(MAX(Count),Count,0),0)
```

Now I just need a way to merge that formula with this one;

```
=IF(AND(Dates >= DATE(2017,9,1), Dates <= DATE(2017,9,EOMONTH(9,0))),)
```

How do I pass the results of the =IF to the =OFFSET?

Comment: Does your [tag:excel] have `maxifs`?

Comment: Trying out =MAXIFS() I get #NAME?, I am presuming that means not?

Comment: If you put a range into that then yes, you don't have maxifs.

Comment: Ah, yes I did try with a range, was that required to get this to work?